# How to configure WCF service or IIS to handle a large amount parameters?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-3.5

I am using .NET 3.5 framework and I have large amount of parameters passing to my wcf:
Is there any configuration I can set either in the web.config or IIS?

```
http://localhost:61819/Services/IRAWorkLoad.svc/GetDLNs?sEcho=1&iColumns=23&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&mDataProp_2=2&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bSortable_2=true&mDataProp_3=3&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bSortable_3=true&mDataProp_4=4&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bSortable_4=true&mDataProp_5=5&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bSortable_5=true&mDataProp_6=6&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bSortable_6=true&mDataProp_7=7&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&bSortable_7=true&mDataProp_8=8&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&bSortable_8=true&mDataProp_9=9&sSearch_9=&bRegex_9=false&bSearchable_9=true&bSortable_9=true&mDataProp_10=10&sSearch_10=&bRegex_10=false&bSearchable_10=true&bSortable_10=true&mDataProp_11=11&sSearch_11=&bRegex_11=false&bSearchable_11=true&bSortable_11=true&mDataProp_12=12&sSearch_12=&bRegex_12=false&bSearchable_12=true&bSortable_12=true&mDataProp_13=13&sSearch_13=&bRegex_13=false&bSearchable_13=true&bSortable_13=true&mDataProp_14=14&sSearch_14=&bRegex_14=false&bSearchable_14=true&bSortable_14=true&mDataProp_15=15&sSearch_15=&bRegex_15=false&bSearchable_15=true&bSortable_15=true&mDataProp_16=16&sSearch_16=&bRegex_16=false&bSearchable_16=true&bSortable_16=true&mDataProp_17=17&sSearch_17=&bRegex_17=false&bSearchable_17=true&bSortable_17=true&mDataProp_18=18&sSearch_18=&bRegex_18=false&bSearchable_18=true&bSortable_18=true&mDataProp_19=19&sSearch_19=&bRegex_19=false&bSearchable_19=true&bSortable_19=true&mDataProp_20=20&sSearch_20=&bRegex_20=false&bSearchable_20=true&bSortable_20=true&mDataProp_21=21&sSearch_21=&bRegex_21=false&bSearchable_21=true&bSortable_21=true&mDataProp_22=22&sSearch_22=&bRegex_22=false&bSearchable_22=true&bSortable_22=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&assignType=1
```

My web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.IRAWorkload.Web.Services.IRAWorkLoadAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.IRAWorkload.Web.Services.IRAWorkLoad">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.IRAWorkload.Web.Services.IRAWorkLoadAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Treasury.IRS.HCTC.IRAWorkload.Web.Services.IRAWorkLoad" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: you can set quotas for most things in WCF, are you getting a specific error when passing all these parameters?

Comment: This has nothing to do with WCF configuration and everything to do with the maximum length allowed for a query string by the browser and/or web server.

Comment: Your example query string is 2,033 characters long, so it might work, but it's hideous to read (IMO).  I think it would make more sense to put those parameters into a DTO-type object and pass the object into the method.  A lot more maintainable and easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I think its the limitation of IIS for the parameters. Can you give me an example DTO as a parameter list?